# Javascript Random sleep for a loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a URL opener. I want to give a delay in opening every link. The time should be random. from 2 seconds to 9 seconds.

Can anyone help me how to do that? 
I tried one method which i found on Stack. But the link opens after fixed time. i.e 5 seconds... or any time I give... SO how to make it in random manner?

Code for Form:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
      <br />
      <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onClick="open_all();">
      <br />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
      <br/>
    </form>
```

Code for JS

```
<script>
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
  }
  function open_all() {
        var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
        var urls = urls.split(/\s+/);
        var totalno = urls.length;
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
            s = urls[i];
            if (s) {
                if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://' && s.substr(0, 8) != 'https://')
                    s = 'http://' + s;
                    sleep(5000);
                    window.open(s)
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: DUDDDDDDDE!! Use a setTimeout!! `for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {` YUK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method of the `window` object.

The code won't run here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, but you can see it working **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/q2nqydct/3/)**.

A couple of other things:

- Don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`,
  `onmouseover`, etc.) as they create spaghetti code, cause duplication
  of code and don't follow the W3C DOM Event standard.
- Don't use a `<form>` if you are not submitting data anywhere.

```js
// Get DOM References
var btnGo = document.getElementById("go");
var btnReset = document.getElementById("reset");
var list = document.getElementById("list_urls");

// Set up event handlers:
btnGo.addEventListener("click", open_all);
btnReset.addEventListener("click", function(){ urls.value = ""; });

function open_all() {
  // Separate input into an array
  var urls = list.value.split(/\s+/);
  
  // Loop over the items in the array
  urls.forEach(function(value){
  
    // Get random number between 2 and 8
    var delay = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)) + 2;
  
    // Append "http://" if no protocol present
    var url = (value.indexOf('http://') === -1 && value.indexOf('https://') === -1) ? 
      'http://' + value : value;
    
    // Call the open function after waiting the delay times 1000 (for milliseconds)
    setTimeout(function() { open(url); }, delay * 1000);
    
  });
}

function open(s){
  window.open(s)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" id="go">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Reset!" id="reset">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` with `Math.random()`

```
function createATimeout(link) {
  var duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; // b/w 1 and 6
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.open(link);
  }, duration);
 }
  function open_all() {
        var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
        var urls = urls.split(/\s+/);
        var totalno = urls.length;
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
            s = urls[i];
            if (s) {
                if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://' && s.substr(0, 8) != 'https://')
                    s = 'http://' + s;
                    createATimeout(s);
            }
        }
    }


<form method="post" action="">
      <br />
      <textarea placeholder="enter list of urls" name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onclick="open_all();">
      <br />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
      <br/>
    </form>
```